# Check if value == integer(0) in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm using the `grep` function in R to check if a conditional regular expression is met.

What I have is this:  `grep(expression, string)` where an example might be

```
   value=  grep("\\s[A-z]", "  ")
   value
```

which outputs

> integer(0)

What I want to be able to do is check is if `value == integer(0)` and

return **TRUE** if `value` is `integer(0)`

return **FALSE** if `value` is not `integer(0)`

Is there a way to do this in R? If there are alternatives, I am open to them. For example, grep might have an option to output the result as a logical value,

**TRUE** and **FALSE**, or

**0** and **1** or something related.

Comment: Try `grepl`, it will return boolean output

Comment: If you get integer(0), maybe you can use **length** to judge it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `identical` which is *the safe and reliable way to test two objects for being exactly equal* (from the docs):

```
value = integer(0)

identical(value, integer(0))
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Or do the following check:

```
is.integer(value) && length(value) == 0
# [1] TRUE
```